# Reporting Analysis Steps in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, reports

Is there any way to report all the steps I did within a ArcMap 10 project. this could help me to:

- Make a Metadata description
- Trackback possible errors afterwards and/or control the analysis
- Easier repeat the analysis some other day

When working with scripts you don't need that beacause they clearly describe what has been done but when clicking around it would be fine to be able to see afterwards what was done. So instead of writing it all down to a textdocument I'm searching for an easy and convinient way to save this automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If your analysis is done using the geoprocessing tools, you can open the geoprocessing results tab and see all the tools used in your session or previous sessions.  I have not experimented much with it but looks like you can create python script snippets or save it to a results file (rlt.)  That would be the closest thing.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! Code Snippets can be exported as phyton (right click in the results window on the tool). Still I dind't find any option to export all the steps automatically at once. So it's still a lot of manual work.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ArcGIS Idea that requests a [**Macro Recorder for Python**](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008ILJ&returnUrl=%252Fapex%252FideaList%253Fc%253D09a300000004xET%2526category%253DBusiness%252BAnalyst%252B%25253Fiframe%25253Dtrue%2526p%253D90%2526sort%253Dpopular) which sounds like it may be what you are after.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Would be awesome if this was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the MS Screenrecorder utility.
It captures all your actions on the screen.

Here is the download link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.utilityspotlight2.aspx